# Characterization of Projective Modules

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory

Let $P$ be a module in an abelian category $\mathcal C$ satisfying $Ext(P,M)=0$ for all modules $M \in \mathcal C$.

Can we conclude that $P$ is projective? Any reference for this?

Comment: Hint: long exact sequence for Ext. (your question implicitly presumes we have enough projectives to define Ext, unless you are using the Yoneda definition.) Perhaps you could give some background context for your question? are you working through parts of a book?

Comment: You can use the usual characterization of projectivity in terms of the lifting property (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_module#Lifting_property) and the exact sequence for the $\hom$ and $\mathrm{Ext}$ functors to prove this. This is proved in more or less any textbook on homological algebra.

Comment: @Yemon Choi: In my case I do have enough projectives. However, I am interested about your comment. Couldn't I talk about Ext if I don't have enough projectives? Why? I will appreciate an answer.

Comment: Arold: for the definition of Ext without assuming enough projectives, see how Ext is defined in Maclane's book "Homology."